# How to populate Mongoose subdocument with data from another subdocument

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a MongoDB database containing data about soccer clubs. A club has players and seasons. A player can have a different squad number each season.

Consider the following Mongoose schemas:

```
const clubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    players: [playerSchema],
    seasons: [seasonSchema]
});

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
});

const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    person: personSchema,
    picture: String
});

const seasonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    seasonPlayers: [seasonPlayerSchema]
});

const seasonPlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    player: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Player"
    },
    squadNumber: Number
});
```

How do I retrieve a fully populated `Club` document? So instead of getting something like this:

```
{
  players: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("abc123"),
      person: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe"
      }
      picture: "john.jpg"
    }
  ],
  seasons: [
    name: "2015-2016",
    seasonPlayers: [
      {
        player: ObjectId("abc123"),
        squadNumber: 10
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want something like this:

```
{
  players: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("abc123"),
      person: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe"
      }
      picture: "john.jpg"
    }
  ],
  seasons: [
    name: "2015-2016",
    seasonPlayers: [
      {
        player: {
          person: {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe"
          }
          picture: "john.jpg"
        },
        squadNumber: 10
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dot notation in Mongoose's [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) path to specify the path within the subdocument hierarchy to populate:

```js
Club.findOne().populate('seasons.seasonPlayers.player').exec(function(err, club) {...});
```

Comment: @Korneel Is `playerSchema` only embedded within club documents and not in its own model/collection?

Comment: Indeed, only embedded, not in its own collection

Comment: Ok, then you have all the data you need right in the Club document, right? I don't think Mongoose can't help you with that, you'll just need do your own post-processing to fix up your docs to do your custom "local" population.

Comment: That's what I eventually did, but I thought maybe Mongoose had helper methods for that. It feels like I'm doing something wrong or bad practice. Would it be better practice to use embedded documents instead of refs to data that's already in the document? It's my first project with MongoDB. Should I model my schema in a different way or do you think it makes sense the way I modelled the schema?

Comment: MongoDB schema design is very much about supporting the ways the data is queried and updated, finding the right balance of embedding and referencing. So there's nothing intrinsically wrong with your schema, and I'd say not duplicating data within your doc makes sense.